# Assigning groups using grepl with multiple inputs

Tags: regex, r

I have a dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(name=c("john", "david", "callum", "joanna", "allison", "slocum", "lisa"), id=1:7)
df

     name id
1    john  1
2   david  2
3  callum  3
4  joanna  4
5 allison  5
6  slocum  6
7    lisa  7
```

I have a vector containing regex that I wish to find in the df$name variable:

```
vec <- c("lis", "^jo", "um$")
```

The output I want to get is as follows:

```
     name id group
1    john  1     2
2   david  2    NA
3  callum  3     3
4  joanna  4     2
5 allison  5     1
6  slocum  6     3
7    lisa  7     1
```

I could do this doing the following:

```
df$group <- ifelse(grepl("lis", df$name), 1,
              ifelse(grepl("^jo", df$name), 2,
               ifelse(grepl("um$", df$name), 3,
                 NA)
```

However, I want to do this directly from 'vec'. I am generating different values into vec reactively in a shiny app.  Can I assign groups based on index in vec?

Further, if something like the below happens, the group should be the first appearing.  e.g. 'Callum' is TRUE for 'all' and "um$" but should get a group 1 here.

```
vec <- c("all", "^jo", "um$")
```

Comment: How do you want to deal with the possibility of multiple patterns matching a given name?

Comment: They should be given the first index that they are TRUE for. Eg last example Callum should be 1 as 'all' is in vec before 'um$'

Comment: Something like `apply(df, 1, function(row) which(sapply(vec, function(regex) grepl(regex, row[1]))))` should get you started. It loops through the data frame row by row and for each element checks which regex matches. I'm interested to see what others come up with though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are several options:

```
df$group <- apply(Vectorize(grepl, "pattern")(vec, df$name),
                  1,
                  function(ii) which(ii)[1])
#     name id group
#1    john  1     2
#2   david  2    NA
#3  callum  3     3
#4  joanna  4     2
#5 allison  5     1
#6  slocum  6     3
#7    lisa  7     1
```

---

Use a named vector and merge on it:

```
names(vec) <- seq_along(vec)

df <- merge(df, stack(Vectorize(grep, "pattern", SIMPLIFY=FALSE)(vec, df$name)),
 by.x="id", by.y="values", all.x = TRUE)

df[!duplicated(df$id),] # to keep only the first match
#  id    name  ind
#1  1    john    2
#2  2   david <NA>
#3  3  callum    3
#4  4  joanna    2
#5  5 allison    1
#6  6  slocum    3
#7  7    lisa    1
```

---

A for loop:

```
df$group <- NA

for ( i in rev(seq_along(vec))) {
  TFvec <- grepl(vec[i], df$name)
  df$group[TFvec] <- i
}

df
#     name id group
#1    john  1     2
#2   david  2    NA
#3  callum  3     3
#4  joanna  4     2
#5 allison  5     1
#6  slocum  6     3
#7    lisa  7     1
```

---

Or you can use `outer` with `stri_match_first_regex` from `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
match.mat <- outer(df$name, vec, stri_match_first_regex)
df$group <- apply(match.mat, 1, function(ii) which(!is.na(ii))[1]) 
# [1] for first match in `vec`

#     name id group
#1    john  1     2
#2   david  2    NA
#3  callum  3     3
#4  joanna  4     2
#5 allison  5     1
#6  slocum  6     3
#7    lisa  7     1
```

Answer (score 3):

A vectorised solution, using `rebus` and `stringi`.

```
library(rebus)
library(stringi)
```

Create a regular expression that captures any of the values in `vec`.

```
vec <- c("lis", "^jo", "um$")
(rx <- or1(vec, capture = TRUE))
## <regex> (lis|^jo|um$)
```

Match the regex, then convert to factor and integer.

```
matches <- stri_match_first_regex(df$name, rx)[, 2]
df$group <- as.integer(factor(matches, levels = c("lis", "jo", "um")))
```

`df` now looks like this:

```
     name id group
1    john  1     2
2   david  2    NA
3  callum  3     3
4  joanna  4     2
5 allison  5     1
6  slocum  6     3
7    lisa  7     1
```

Comment: Why not just use `rx <- paste(vec, collapse = "|")` instead using an extra package?

Comment: @Jaap Because I was shamelessly hyping my own package.  It is a little overkill for such a simple regex, I must admit.