# assign groups depending on pairwise combinations within string

Tags: r, string, grouping

I have a big df with the following structure

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), name = c("aa", "ab", "ac",  "aa", "aab", "aac", "aabc")), .Names = c("id", "name"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")

df  

   id  name
1  1   aa
2  2   ab
3  3   ac
4  4   aa
5  5   aab
6  6   aac
7  7   aabc
```

I would like to create a new column group depending two character strings in column name (here aa, ab, ac) to achieve something like

```
df  

   id  name   group
1  1   aa     1
2  2   ab     2
3  3   ac     3
4  4   aa     1
5  5   aab    1
5  5   aab    2
6  6   aac    1
6  6   aac    3
7  7   aabc   1
7  7   aabc   2
7  7   aabc   3
```

While assigning groups for the two character strings is straight forward I struggle to find an efficient way to include the pairwise combinations of longer strings. I thought about splitting each string with nchar>2 into all the possible pairwise combinations and assign them to the respective groups but wonder if there is a better way.

Further notes

1. only pairwise combinations found in df (not all possible combinations)
2. order of the two character string does not matter (e.g. ab=ba)
3. only unique recombinations of longer strings (e.g. aaab is just aa and ab) d

Similar question without the recombination problem [Assigning groups using grepl with multiple inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34702882/assigning-groups-using-grepl-with-multiple-inputs)

Comment: I don't understand your example. Why do the last three entries with `aabc` get assigned to three different groups? Ditto for `aab` and `aac`?

Comment: bc you can basically split the strings with more than 2 characters into combinations of the two character ones (e.g. aab can be split into "aa" as well as the "ab" combination) and than assigned to the respective groups

Comment: I still don't understand. Why doesn't `aabc` get assigned a new group? I understand the permutation bit (at least I think I do), however you're still left with two additional characters that you seem to ignore. Could you clarify the rules in your original question? Are you after all possible 2-char combinations of unique characters in a string?

Comment: I will reframe the question

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following

```
# Your data
df <- structure(
    list(
        id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), 
        name = c("aa", "ab", "ac",  "aa", "aab", "aac", "aabc")), 
    .Names = c("id", "name"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")

# Create all possible 2char combinations from unique chars in string
group <- lapply(strsplit(df$name, ""), function(x) 
    unique(apply(combn(x, 2), 2, function(y) paste0(y, collapse = ""))));

# Melt and add original data
require(reshape2);
df2 <- melt(group);
df2 <- cbind.data.frame(
    df2, 
    df[match(df2$L1, df$id), ]);
df2$group <- as.numeric(as.factor(df2$value));
df2;
#    value L1 id name group
#1      aa  1  1   aa     1
#2      ab  2  2   ab     2
#3      ac  3  3   ac     3
#4      aa  4  4   aa     1
#5      aa  5  5  aab     1
#5.1    ab  5  5  aab     2
#6      aa  6  6  aac     1
#6.1    ac  6  6  aac     3
#7      aa  7  7 aabc     1
#7.1    ab  7  7 aabc     2
#7.2    ac  7  7 aabc     3
#7.3    bc  7  7 aabc     4
```

Explanation: `strsplit` splits the strings from `df$name` into char vectors. `combn` creates all 2-char combinations based on those char vectors. `paste0` and `unique` keeps the concatenated unique 2-char combinations.

Note that this *almost* reproduces your example. That's because in my case, `aabc` also gives rise to group `4 = bc`.

---

## Update 1

You can filter entries based on a list of 2-char comparisons

```
# Filter entries
filter <- c("aa", "ab", "ac");
df2 <- df2[df2$value %in% filter, ]

# Clean up df2 to be consistent with OPs request
df2 <- df2[, -(1:2)];
df2;
#    id name group
#1    1   aa     1
#2    2   ab     2
#3    3   ac     3
#4    4   aa     1
#5    5  aab     1
#5.1  5  aab     2
#6    6  aac     1
#6.1  6  aac     3
#7    7 aabc     1
#7.1  7 aabc     2
#7.2  7 aabc     3
```

---

## Update 2

You can also create a filter dynamically, by selecting those `value` entries that are represented as 2-char strings in the original `dataframe` (in this case `aa`, `ab` and `ac`).

```
filter <- unique(unlist(group[sapply(group, function(x) length(x) == 1)]));
```

Comment: Wow that's almost it. Instead of all combinations I only consider pairwise combinations found in df (means only aa, ab and ac).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "pairwise combinations found in df". You can see all 2-char combinations in `df2$value`. So what is your argument for *excluding* `bc`?

Comment: it is not appearing in df as a sole pairwise combination.

Comment: What is a "sole pairwise combination"? Your rules say to construct all 2-char combinations. `bc` is one of those combinations.

Comment: Ah I see. So you only want combinations of `aa`, `ab` and `ac`. That seems arbitrary to me but I don't know the full story. I will add the filtering step you suggest in my solution for completeness.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarifications; I understand now. I've added a second update that should do what you want.

Comment: Could you update your question and include sample data that results in the error you mention?

Comment: It's hard to say what's going on without the actual data. Your best bet is to construct a minimal example, and post the data and code that gives the error. Perhaps `df$name` contains empty strings? Or strings of length 1?

Comment: could not even rerun the example above so I restarted R and now it works. Its getting late. Thanks again for your time and input